# Search algorithms in julia

Tags: algorithm, search, julia

I've been trying to implement the basic search algorithms: Sequential search for ordered and unordered arrays and the binary search algorithms, as part of a [package](https://github.com/Dawny33/Algorithms.jl).

So, this is the implementation:

```
"""
`seqsearch{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T)` ↦ found::Bool
Searches for an item using the **Sequential Search** approach.
"""
function seqsearch{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T)
  index = 1
  found = false

  while index <= length(x) && !found
    x[index] == item ? found = true : index += 1
  end

  return found
end


"""
`ordseqsearch{T}::(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T) ↦ found::Bool`
Searches for an item in a sorted array using the **Sequential Search** approach.
"""
function ordseqsearch{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T)
  index = 1
  found = false
  stop  = false

  while index <= length(x) && !found && !stop
    x[index] == item ? found = true : x[index] > item ? stop = true : index += 1
  end

  return found
end


"""
`binarysearch{T}::(x::AbstractArray(T), item::T) ↦ found::Bool`
Searches for an item in a sorted array using the **Binary Search** algorithm
"""
function binarysearch{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T)
  first = 1
  last = length(x)
  found = false

  while first <= last && !found
    middle = fld(first+last, 2)

    if x[middle] == item
      found = true
    else
      if item > middle
        first = middle + 1
      else
        last = middle - 1
      end
    end

  end

  return found
end
```

I want to make the implementations as fast as possible, with as less dependencies as possible.

So, are there any ways to make it cleaner (and/or) faster?

Comment: I didn't use the `? :` construct for the `if else` in the binary search implementations, as I felt it'd be very long and confusing.

Comment: (Your "backtick-quoting" in the doc comments is inconsistent.)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for pointing it out. Would fix in the latest commit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of variables **`found`** and **`stop`**, and just return **`true`** on match, **`false`** after the body (which means there was no match). The reason is that you keep checking in the loop conditional their value; that's unnecessary computation.

**Edit** Actually, it would be even better if you returned the index of the found element instead of just a boolean value indicating whether the element is in the input array. In case there is no match, return a value that cannot be a valid array index, for example, -1.

Comment: Initially, my idea was to return a tuple like this `(Boolean, element)`, then I went ahead with just returning the Boolean value. Maybe I should reconsider :)

Comment: @Dawny33 In Julia, is there some **`None`** keyword à la Python? If yes, you could return an index on match, and that very **`None`** on failure.

Comment: @coderodde there is `nothing` of type `Void`, but that would make the function type unstable (could be `Void` or `Int`,ie: `Union{Void, Int}` see  [`@code_warntype`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype) macro), you could either return 0 or -1 as you mention or a `Nullable{Int}` for it to be type stable and performant.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this code is more readable? It just skips elements which are too small (and stops iteration either on an element sought, a too big element or at the list's end) then tests if the right element is found.

```
function ordseqsearch{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, item::T)
  index = 1

  while index <= length(x) && x[index] < item
    index += 1
  end

  return index <= length(x) && x[index] == item
end
```