# Sort Algorithms in Julia

Tags: algorithm, sorting, julia

Similar to this question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/121865/90680), I am trying to implement sort algorithms in Julia, as part of a [package](https://github.com/Dawny33/SearchSortAlgos.jl).

The code for the implementation is as follows:

```
"""
The swapping function implementation
"""
function swap!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, a::T, b::T)

  tmp = x[a]
  x[a] = x[b]
  x[b] = tmp
  return x

end


"""
`insertsort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}) ↦ x::AbstractArray`
Sorts an array using the **Insertion Sort** approach.
"""
function insertsort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T})

  for index = 2:length(x)

    current  = x[index]
    position = index

    # For sublist sorting
    while position > 1 && x[position - 1] > current
      x[position] = x[position - 1]
      position -= 1
    end

    x[position] = current

  end

  return x
end


"""
`bubblesort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}) ↦ x::AbstractArray`
Sorts an array using the **Bubble Sort** approach.
"""
function bubblesort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T})

  for i in 2:length(x)
    for j in 1:length(x)-1
      if x[j] > x[j+1]
        swap!(x, j, j+1)
      end
    end
  end

  return x
end


"""
`selectsort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}) ↦ x::AbstractArray`
Sorts an array using the **Selection Sort** approach.
"""
function selectsort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T})

  for i in 1:length(x)-1
    iMin = i
    for j in i+1:length(x)
      if x[j] < x[iMin]
        iMin = j
      end
    end

    swap!(x, i, iMin)
  end

  return x
end


"""
`quicksort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}) ↦ x::AbstractArray`
Sorts an array using the **Quick Sort** approach.
"""
function quicksort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}, first::T = 1, last::T = length(x))

  if last > first

    pivot       = x[first]
    left, right = first, last

    while left <= right
      while x[left] < pivot
        left += 1
      end
      while x[right] > pivot
        right -= 1
      end
      if left <= right
        swap!(x, left, right)
        left += 1
        right -= 1
      end
    end

    quicksort!(x, first, right)
    quicksort!(x, left, last)
  end

  return x
end


"""
`mergesort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T}) ↦ x::AbstractArray`
Sorts an array using the **Merge Sort** approach.
"""
function mergesort!{T}(x::AbstractArray{T})

  if length(x) > 1
    mid    = div(length(x), 2)
    left   = mergesort!(x[1:mid])
    right  = mergesort!(x[mid+1:length(x)])
    result = Array(eltype(left), length(left) + length(right))

    k = 1

    while length(left) != 0 && length(right) != 0
      if left[1] <= right[1]
        result[k] = left[1]
        left      = left[2:end]
      else
        result[k] = right[1]
        right = right[2:end]
      end
      k += 1
    end

    while length(left) != 0
      result[k] = left[1]
      left = left[2:end]
      k += 1
    end

    while length(right) != 0
      result[k] = right[1]
      right = right[2:end]
      k += 1
    end

  for i = 1:length(x)
    x[i] = result[i]
  end

  end

  return x
end
```

All the sort algorithms are in-place. Are there any ways I can make speed up the implementations along with optimizing code for performance and quality?

(The reason I created a separate `swap` function, rather than doing `x[a], x[b] = x[b], x[a]` is that I felt it'd look more neat. Need your views on that too,)

Comment: **`result = Array(eltype(left), length(left) + length(right))`**: are you creating an array right there?

Comment: @coderodde Yes.  `eltype` gives the `Type` and `length(left) + length(right)` gives the requisite length

Comment: For this very reason your mergesort is **not** in-place.

Comment: @coderodde I should confess that that was a hack to make it look like in-place :)   (Would be changing a later).

Comment: Actually there exists an in-place mergesort, yet, as far as I recall, it's slower by the factor of \$\Theta(\log n)\$.

Comment: If you're developing a package, note that insertion sort, quicksort, partial quicksort, and merge sort are all available as choices for the `alg` argument to the `sort` and `sort!` functions in the base library. [See here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/sort/#sorting-algorithms)

Comment: @AlexA. Yeah, I know abt that library.  I'm developing my library more in the perspective of search and sort algos. in both competitive programming and ML!  So, its a bit different from `Base.sort`

Answer (score 1):

Your mergesort has a serious issue. If you run

```
size=100000
x=rand(1:(2^62),size)
@time(mergesort!(x))
```

you will find that your algorithm is allocating ram 2.34 **million** times, and is allocating **37.4 GB** The problem comes from this block:

```
while length(left) != 0 && length(right) != 0
  if left[1] <= right[1]
    result[k] = left[1]
    left      = left[2:end]
  else
    result[k] = right[1]
    right = right[2:end]
  end
  k += 1
end
```

If you instead write,

```
left_ind = 1
right_ind = 1
r_ind = 1
while left_ind<=length(left) && right_ind<=length(right)
    if left[left_ind]<right[right_ind]
        result[r_ind]=left[left_ind]
        left_ind += 1
    else
        result[r_ind]=right[right_ind]
        right_ind += 1
    end
    r_ind += 1
end
if left_ind<=length(left)
    result[r_ind:end] = left[left_ind:end]
elseif right_ind<=length(right)
    result[r_ind:end] = right[right_ind:end]
end
result
```

This drops the time from 3.7 seconds to .2 seconds, and memory allocation to 57MB

Comment: It turns out that since you were creating n arrays when merging arrays of size n, you managed to make a version of mergesort that had runtime ~ O(n^2log(n)).